# Chron Job Expression

Tags: cron

Need a cron job expression which should run at every 15 min in [12:00 AM To 3:59 AM, 12 PM to 3:59 PM] using Java. Can some one please help.

Is it possible to maintain intervals and frequency at the same time?

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-cron-expression